# Receive Push notification in iOS when the application is in terminated state

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift3, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase Cloud messaging for both Android and iOS application of mine.

I am using **data** key in **FCM request payload**, which only shows the notification when the App is in either background or running state. The notification is not received when the app is in terminated state.

Whereas, when I use **notification** key in **FCM request payload**, I receive notification even in terminated state too.

The reason behind using data key is to modify the handling of the action, the way of presentation. In Android app, I have customised the behaviour of notification, like the Vibration, Sound etc.

I want to do the same in iOS.

Now, if both the key's are passed in the request payload, by default, notifcation key is handled by both the OS.

Answer (score 2):

iOS devices cannot receive `data-messages` when the app is terminated.
This is a limitation of iOS so firebase-messaging cannot really solve it.

Comment: is it just firebase ? or we can't do it in native APNS too ?

Comment: If all you need is changing the presentation, check the mutable-content option